# Display an image scraped from a website in jsoup

Tags: java, netbeans, jsoup

I'm making a small application in Java that requires me to scrape an image from a website and display it in a GUI. Now I'm not asking how to get the image's absolute URL, I'm asking how I can display it once I've gotten the absolute URL. I'm using the jsoup library as the web scraper.

Comment: Have you thought about maybe using a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following piece of code to get the desired output shown in the image below (Use appropriate imports):

```
    BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyAppName");
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
    frame.getContentPane().add(picLabel);
```

> For setRequestProperty, use any string in place of MyAppName, it's just a value to the User-Agent attribute in the http request made by your app

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWEoH.png)